# sql Case condition for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a query to get below columns as output

```
SELECT person_number,
       second_year_ltp,
       second_year_salary,
       one_year_bonus,
       one_year_salary,
       one_year_ltp,
       third_year_bonus,
       three_year_ltp,
       three_year_salary,
       current_ltp,
       current_salary,
       current_bonus,
       current_year,
       previous_year,
       second_year,
       third_year,
       fourth_year
FROM   comp_sal
```

I want to change values of multiple columns if the sysdate >= '01-04-2022', I cannot write the below code as it will give an error -

```
select person_number,
 CASE
              WHEN to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022'
              THEN
                    current_bonus        one_year_bonus,
                     current_ltip       one_year_ltp,
                     current_salary     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus     second_year_bonus,
                     one_year_ltp     second_year_ltp,
                     one_year_salary    second_year_salary,
                     second_year_bonus  third_year_bonus,
                     second_year_ltp   three_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary three_year_salary
                     
                     else 
                     second_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus,
                     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_ltp,
                     third_year_bonus,
                     three_year_ltp,
                     three_year_salary,
                     current_ltip,
                     current_salary
                     end 
                     from comp_sal
```

Will I have to write the case when for each column ? is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: It is one `CASE` expression per column/alias.

Comment: Number of column doesn't match. Please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write one case statement per column.

```
select person_number,
 (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022' THEN current_ltip       ELSE second_year_ltp END) one_year_bonus,
 (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022' THEN current_salary       ELSE second_year_salary END) one_year_ltp,
 (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022' THEN one_year_salary       ELSE one_year_bonus END) one_year_salary
from comp_sal
```

Or you can write two query then combine both with union all. Number of columns in both query should match in appropriate order.

```
SELECT               person_number,
                     current_bonus        one_year_bonus,
                     current_ltip       one_year_ltp,
                     current_salary     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus     second_year_bonus,
                     one_year_ltp     second_year_ltp,
                     one_year_salary    second_year_salary,
                     second_year_bonus  third_year_bonus,
                     second_year_ltp   three_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary three_year_salary
                     
from comp_sal where to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022'
union all
select               person_number,                     
                     second_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus,
                     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_ltp,
                     third_year_bonus,
                     three_year_ltp,
                     three_year_salary,
                     current_ltip                                        
from comp_sal where to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') < '01-04-2022'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have write a separate case expression for each column. Alternatively, you can write two separate SQL statements, one with your condition in the `where` clause, and the other has the inverse of it, and combine the two queries using `union all`

Comment: perfect. I think this will be the best. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it is oracle, As an alternative, you can write this as pl/sql block as follows:

```
declare
v_query varchar2(4000);
begin
 if to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= '01-04-2022' then
-- select one set of columns
v_query := 'SELECT person_number,
                     current_bonus        one_year_bonus,
                     current_ltip       one_year_ltp,
                     current_salary     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus     second_year_bonus,
                     one_year_ltp     second_year_ltp,
                     one_year_salary    second_year_salary,
                     second_year_bonus  third_year_bonus,
                     second_year_ltp   three_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary three_year_salary ';
else
-- select another set of columns
v_query := 'SELECT person_number, second_year_ltp,
                     second_year_salary,
                     one_year_bonus,
                     one_year_salary,
                     one_year_ltp,
                     third_year_bonus,
                     three_year_ltp,
                     three_year_salary,
                     current_ltip,
                     current_salary ';
end if;
 -- CONCAT FROM CLAUSE IN THE QUERY
v_auery := v_query ||' FROM comp_sal ';

-- run the query and store the result set in a table
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE result_set as '||v_query;

-- your final result will be in the table result_set
end;
```